# Optimizing Rank Aggregation of Two Different Methods in Information Retrieval

Tags: optimization, information-retrieval, ranking, aggregation

As the title suggests, I would like to train a rank-aggregating model. My target problem is to rank `text2`s from a database as best as possible to a given query, `text1`. What I have available is as follows:

- I have `text1`, with some features, let's call them `a,b,c`
- I have `text2`, with features `d,e,f`
- Every `text1` has a corresponding target `text2`
- For every `text1`, I have `ranks1`, with rankings of the top 100 `text2`s that have been ranked according to query `text1` using `method A`
- For every `text1`, I have `ranks2`, with rankings of the top 100 `text2`s that have been ranked according to query `text1` using `method B`

I want my model to best apply appropriate weightings to each of the two ranking methods dependent on features `a,b,c,d,e,f`. Ultimately, the model should learn from my large dataset (in the format as described above), how to best aggregate the two rankings, so as to optimize a given metric (e.g. MAP, MRR). Intuitively, the model should learn to generally place the target `text2` as high as possible, according to all the information it has.

I would greatly appreciate any advice or insights, or for any pointers in a direction which would be useful to me. Thank you in advance!